# How to variable arguments in Python Subprocess

Tags: python, arguments, subprocess, syslog

I am writing a python script and then using a subprocess to log to the syslog.  The log structure is made up of variables:

Sensor
Alert

Each variable is pulled from a database so to get the correct sensor and the correct alert.  My problem is that I can not build the alert because I am messing up the variables as arguments.

```
sensor = 12345
alert_text = "Help me Help me."

subprocess.call("sudo logger -t ALERT --priority alert -- ALERT: Sensor: '%s', Alert: '%s'" % sa, alert_text, shell=True)
```

In my code above the syslog comment is constructed of the "Sensor ID" and then the "Alert Test" so that log entry should read as:

```
ALERT: Sensor: 12345 Alert: Help me Help me.
```

I am getting the "Not enough arguments to build a sentence" error.  I suspect I am submitting my arguments incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need pass tuple to string formatting:

```
alert_text = "Help me Help me"
subprocess.call("sudo logger -t ALERT --priority alert -- ALERT: Sensor: '%s', Alert: %s" % (sa, alert_text), shell=True)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is really close.  The only problem is that the output is `ALERT: Sensor: 12345, Alert: (Help me Help me!,)`  this has the extra parenthesis and a comma

Comment: Same output, no chage

Comment: I've tried this, and my output is `ALERT: Sensor: 12345, Alert: Help me Help me.`

Comment: do not use `shell=True` here. Imagine what happens: `alert_text = "Help me ... you're my only hope"`. You can [use syslog without invoking the shell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28554785/4279)

Answer (score 0):

`% sa, alert_text` to `% (sa, alert_text)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `format()` function. Clear and more elegant.

```
subprocess.call("sudo logger -t ALERT --priority alert -- ALERT: Sensor: {}, Alert: {}".format(sa, alert_text), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `subprocess` module to log to syslog. You could [use `logging` module instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging.handlers

# .. check what address you should be using for a domain socket - it’s system dependent.
# For example, on Linux it’s usually ‘/dev/log’ but on OS/X it’s ‘/var/run/syslog’.
address = '/dev/log'

# handlers parameter is available since Python 3.3+ (write custom code for earlier versions)
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address)])

sensor = 12345
alert_text = "Help me Help me."
logging.warning("Sensor: %d, Alert: %s", sensor, alert_text)
```

It writes to syslog on my machine:

```
Feb 17 05:39:13 ubuntu WARNING:root:Sensor: 12345, Alert: Help me Help me.
```

If you want; you can use `subprocess`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

sensor = 12345
alert_text = "Help me Help me."
check_call('sudo logger -t ALERT --priority alert'.split() +
           ["ALERT: Sensor: {sensor} Alert: {alert}".format(sensor=sensor, alert=alert_text)])
```

Note: `subprocess` module does not use shell by default therefore you don't need to escape anything. In particular, you don't need the single quotes here.

There is also [`syslog` stdlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/syslog.html).